# I didn't see the video on the webpage which load from Kurento media server

Tags: kurento

I found out the error in the Terminal
Caused by: org.kurento.jsonrpc.JsonRpcException: [KurentoClient]  Exception connecting to WebSocket server ws://localhost:8888/kurento

Then I tried the command "sudo netstat -tupan | grep kurento"
But, I didn't see the listening port "8888".

Could someone help me with this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I modified the port of Kurento Media server from 8888 to 8899 at the file /etc/kurento/kurento.conf.json then the server ran very well.